# Majordomo code from the zeromq guide

Tags: zeromq

I am unable to understand an aspect of the majordomo C code found in the zeromq guide. When the worker replies to a request, how does it get routed to the correct client. When the request is sent to the worker, I am not able to see how the client identity is being communicated? So am not able to understand how the reply gets routed properly. Here is the function in mdbroker.c which sends a message to the worker.

```
static void
s_worker_send (worker_t *self, char *command, char *option, zmsg_t *msg)
{
  msg = msg? zmsg_dup (msg): zmsg_new ();

  //  Stack protocol envelope to start of message
  if (option)
     zmsg_pushstr (msg, option);
  zmsg_pushstr (msg, command);
  zmsg_pushstr (msg, MDPW_WORKER);

  //  Stack routing envelope to start of message
  zmsg_wrap (msg, zframe_dup (self->identity));

  if (self->broker->verbose) {
    zclock_log ("I: sending %s to worker",
        mdps_commands [(int) *command]);
    zmsg_dump (msg);
  }
  zmsg_send (&msg, self->broker->socket);
}
```

I probably am not understanding how identities and router sockets work. Any help will be appreciated. I am still stuck here..

Answer (score 0):

The request starts with a message envelope, that includes the identity of the client as seen by the broker. The worker gets this envelope, saves it, and puts it back on the reply. Then the broker can route the reply to the correct client. This is built in to the REQ and REP socket types.